# jOOQ mapper from POJO to Record

Tags: java, jooq

Using jOOQ 3.8.6, I had to implement [record mapper](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/RecordMapper.java) to convert from Record to Pojo because of some UDT in the fetched records.
Now, I wonder how to do the opposite when creating a Record from a Pojo.

```
public void update(MyTable pojo){ 
  MyTableRecord record = dsl.newRecord(tables.MyTable.MY_TABLE, pojo);
  record.store();
}
```

I have a

```
org.jooq.exception.MappingException: An error ocurred when mapping record from class tables.pojos.MyTable
```

because of a

```
Caused by: org.jooq.exception.DataTypeException: Cannot convert from MyType (class udt.pojos.MyType) to class udt.records.MyTypeRecord
```

I think I have to register a custom converter from POJO to Record. 
Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`RecordUnmapper` feature (issue #2520)](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2520), which has not been implemented yet as of jOOQ 3.8

You have at least these two possible workarounds:

1. Don't use a `RecordMapper`, but a [`Converter`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types/) or data type [`Binding`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/) instead. Those will allow you to implement the conversion in two ways, and it will not only apply to your POJOs, but also to your Records
2. Do a manual "unmapping" step, prior to calling [`DSLContext.newRecord(Table, Object)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#newRecord-org.jooq.Table-java.lang.Object-)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up here with Google. As of jOOQ 3.13, the statements from OP work well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) to convert a POJO to a Record. For example:

```
 ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
 WorkerRecord workerRecord = modelMapper.map(worker, WorkerRecord.class);
```